# How to prevent the mouse cursor from being hidden after calling CComboBox::ShowDropDown?

Tags: mfc, mouse, visibility, ccombobox

In my MFC application, when I call CComboBox::ShowDropDown(), the mouse cursor is hidden until interaction with the combo box completes (when the combo box loses focus.)  It doesn't reappear when the mouse is moved, like it does with edit boxes.

How can I keep the mouse cursor from being hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call

```
SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW));
```

immediately after the ShowDropDown() call.

Comment: I used this statement and got this error:  `'LoadCursorA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int' to 'LPCSTR'` what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: First parameter to LoadCursor must be `NULL` if you want to use one of the pre-defined cursor constants. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.